# Youtube API to fetch all the vidoes uploaded in a channel using channel id

Tags: android, api, youtube

I have created a test youtube account. I want to retreive all the vidoes uploaded in this channel using channel id and show  all these vidoes to the users without authentication. In the below YouTube api page:

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests#playlists
```

I found a API that can be used for unathenticated requests to fetch all the uploaded videos using channel id and API KEY.

```
You can request information about information about a channel's public playlists without authentication. When you submit an unauthenticated request, you need to include the key argument that specifies the unique API key for the application making the request. For example, this request retrieves the playlists associated with the GoogleDevelopers channel.

GET {base_URL}/playlists?part=snippet
                        &channelId=UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw
                        &key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

where base_URL is : `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3`

This gives me a response in the `Developers console`. But When I fire a `Http request`, it throws below error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

What is wrong here. Why I'm getting a response in the developers console without authentication and why error is thrown when direct HTTP request is made?

Problem Solved:

```
I was using OAuth key instead of API key. I created server key and used this key to send HTTP request and now getting the Json response.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can embed youtube in Fragment using webview. I have achieved this with the help of WebView also I have uploaded source on Github

https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Universal-Web-Content-Loader/blob/master/src/com/serveroverload/universal_webloader/HomeActivity.java

you can display any channel on your app with the help of just 1 line

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.frag_root, UniversalWebViewFragment.newInstance(YOU_TUBE_DEMO_URL, false)).commit();
```

where YOU_TUBE_DEMO_URL will redirect to AndroidDevelopers Official channel.

Plus you do not need any kind of authentication or external jar to do so.